# Nested tableview scrolling issues

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

The nested tableview initially brings the data very stable, but when I scroll down and go up again, the data is gone. Below is my extension tableview algorithm.

I couldn't find a solution why this data is lost. TableView Extensions:

I wonder if there is a problem with the algorithm I am doing, I do not fully understand. I am waiting for your help. Thank you very much in advance.

```
I take the data from listesiparis and place it in the tableview inside the tableview. As you can see from the coding, there seems to be no problem. If it's not a problem, why not work?
```

[first open - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRk4S.png)
[when you scroll up and down - image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1tR37.png)

```
tb.delegate = self
tb.dataSource = self
tb.estimatedRowHeight = 150
tb.rowHeight = UITableView.automaticDimension

struct listesiparis {
        var adet : Int
        var fiyat : Double
        var urunadi : String
        var urunid : String
        var urunresim : String
        var urunadi_en: String
    }
    struct siparis {
        var docid : String
        var siparis : [listesiparis]
        var tarih : String
    }
    var siparisArray = [siparis]()

extension MusteriRapor: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView == tb {
            return siparisArray.count
        } else {
            guard let selectedCell = tableView.superview?.superview?.superview as? MusteriRaporCell,
                  let selectedIndexPath = tb.indexPath(for: selectedCell) else {
                return 0
            }
            let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath.row
            return siparisArray[selectedRow].siparis.count
        }
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView == tb {
            let cell = tb.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MusteriRaporCell
            let item = siparisArray[indexPath.row]
            cell.date.text = item.tarih

            cell.tbnestted.delegate = self
            cell.tbnestted.dataSource = self

            cell.siparisArray = item.siparis
            cell.tbnestted.reloadData()

            let nestedTableViewHeight = CGFloat(item.siparis.count * 70) + 24
            cell.cardconsttraint.constant = nestedTableViewHeight

            return cell
        } else {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! MusteriRaporNestedCell
            
            guard let selectedCell = tableView.superview?.superview?.superview as? MusteriRaporCell,
                  let selectedIndexPath = tb.indexPath(for: selectedCell) else {
                return cell
            }
            let selectedRow = selectedIndexPath.row
            let selectedSiparis = siparisArray[selectedRow]
            
            let nestedItem = selectedSiparis.siparis
            
            cell.urunadi.text = nestedItem[indexPath.row].urunadi
            
            return cell
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: kindly provide the full code snippet with titles or class name as description

Comment: cell.tbnestted.delegate = self,
          cell.tbnestted.dataSource = self,
cell.tbnestted.reloadData(), remove these line also and declare them inside the MsuteriReporCell

Comment: Thank you for the correct method. Frankly, after I wrote this question, I did the process again as you said and it happened.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of referencing `tableView.superview?.superview?.superview`, you might have better results if you set the inner `tableView`'s `dataSource` to be the custom `UITableViewCell` subclass for your outer `tableView` instead of the containing `ViewController`.

Then, you'll be doing a lot less work inside your View Controller's `cellForRowAt` method, since half of it can now be handled by your outer table view's `cellForRowAt` implementation.  Just use `@IBOutlets` to pass along any relevant data from the View Controller to the outer `tableView`'s custom cell class.

Here is a minimal working example to see if you like the results:

**View Controller**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeMenu: UITableView!
    
    var coffees: [[String]] = [
        ["Hot Coffees", "Plain", "Mocha", "Latte", "Cappuccino", "Turtle Pecan"],
        ["Iced Coffees", "Iced Vanilla", "Iced Caramel", "Iced Mocha", "Praline"],
        ["Frozen Coffees", "Mint Chip", "Cinnamon", "Triple Chocolate", "Caramel Swirl"],
        ["Teas", "Chai Spice", "Black Tea", "Green Tea", "Jasmine Tea", "Oolong Tea"],
        ["Other", "Water", "Hot Chocolate", "Apple Juice", "Milk"]
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        coffeeMenu.dataSource = self
        coffeeMenu.register(UINib(nibName: "CoffeeCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CoffeeCell_ID")
        coffeeMenu.rowHeight = 220
    }
}

extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return coffees.count
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = coffeeMenu.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoffeeCell_ID", for: indexPath) as! CoffeeCell
        cell.coffeeClassName.text = coffees[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.coffees = Array(coffees[indexPath.row].dropFirst(1))
        cell.coffeeNestedTable.dataSource = cell
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Outer Table View Cell (Custom Cocoa Touch Subclass)**

```
import UIKit

class CoffeeCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeClassName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeNestedTable: UITableView!
    
    var coffees: [String]?
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        coffeeNestedTable.dataSource = self
        coffeeNestedTable.register(UINib(nibName: "CoffeeNestedCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "CoffeeNestedCell_ID")
        coffeeNestedTable.rowHeight = 50
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
    
}

extension CoffeeCell: UITableViewDataSource {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return coffees?.count ?? 0
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = coffeeNestedTable.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CoffeeNestedCell_ID", for: indexPath) as! CoffeeNestedCell
        cell.coffeeCupPic.image = (indexPath.row % 2 == 0 ? UIImage(systemName: "cup.and.saucer.fill") : UIImage(systemName: "cup.and.saucer"))
        cell.coffeeName.text = coffees?[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

**Inner Table View Cell (Custom Cocoa Touch Subclass)**

```
import UIKit

class CoffeeNestedCell: UITableViewCell {
    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeCupPic: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var coffeeName: UILabel!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    }
}
```

Nib file for the `CoffeeCell` (reuse identifier is "CoffeeCell_ID"):
[image: outer table view custom cell image]

Nib file for the `CoffeeNestedCell` (reuse identifier is "CoffeeNestedCell_ID"):
[image: inner table view custom cell image]

Comment: Thank you for the correct method. Frankly, after I wrote this question, I did the process again as you said and it happened. I found your answer helpful but only gave feedback as it wanted 15 reputation points. Thank you.

Comment: @H0neyHunter You're welcome!  I'm glad you found this method helpful.  If it solves your problem in exactly the way you're looking for, you can 'accept' it by clicking on the checkmark - this doesn't require any reputation.  Don't do this if you're still looking for other answers, though, as questions with accepted answers get less attention.